# Make Grails action available only for includes

Tags: grails, groovy, action

I have a Grails controller with multiple actions. For now all actions are available for user calls (I can access them from my browser), even the ones that should be called only from withing the g:include tag. I want to restrict access to such actions from the browser. I cannot mark action as protected because in this case I will not be able to include this action in a view for another controller.

Is there any practice how to encapsulate actions in such situations?

Comment: Well there's probably many way of doing it - requestMappings beeing one of them -http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/requestMappings.html but I'll require the spring security plugin, and that you setup roles. I'm using it and it works well for me, but that doesn't mean it will be your silver bullet.

Comment: This is the section you want to look at: 4.1 Defining Secured Annotations

Comment: Do you think it's OK to handle visibility scope using security plugin? I hoped that there is something like allowedMethods property. It specifies what methods are allowed for the action. It would be great to have the possibility also to forbid access to action completely from outside, but make it available for internal calls.

Comment: If I am not wrong then you want an action that can only accessible in a gsp and can not be called from browser. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, You are completely right. I don't want to expose actions that are not pages.

Comment: Then my suggestion is to use custom tag library. As action, in tablib you have full grails power and a tag library is only accessible in gsp  because it processed on server.

Comment: @user1690588 custom tag library is a good workaround but it is not an options for me since I have too many such actions. Also it sounds logical to store actions that generate, for example, templates in controllers and I would not move them to taglibs. In other case I will have functionality for one specific page stored in two places - controller and taglib.

Comment: @Yuriy as user1690588 says Taglibs are the way to go then, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Yuriy :- actions are created for accepting requests and sending responses and user can access them via browser. And a taglib is used for sending data/template to view/action and user have no control on taglib because they are processed on server side. 

A problem can be solved by many ways, keep on searching, may be you got best solution. Taglib is the one way to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to “protect” actions from being accessible via a URL is to not provide a URL mapping to them.  The default url mapping looks something like this…

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

That “/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?” mapping is convenient for simple crud apps and demos well but for any substantial app you should almost always remove that.  Without it, only the actions you explicitly expose are accessible.